# Debian: Несколько IP, выбор основного

Tags: ip, debian, eth0

Есть сервер на Debian 6.0.*,4 внешних IP по одному eth0.

```
root@aaa:/# ifconfig -a    
eth0   ... 100.100.101.201    
eth0:0 ... 100.100.101.202    
eth0:1 ... 100.100.102.201    
eth0:2 ... 100.100.102.202
```

Соответственно, исходящий IP получается первый (*.101.201), но почему-то не так давно он сам сменился на последний (*.102.202), причем конфиг сетевого интерфейса не менялся...

Вопрос: Как жестко указать что основной IP - первый, и все исходящие соединения нужно делать из-под него?
Или скажем жестко указать, что почтовый клиент (курьер) лез из-под первого... есть варианты?

PS. Траблз был в том, что PTR запись была прописана только на первый IP, и почта тупо перестала доставляться...

Comment: Попробуйте указать везде один и тот IP до основательного решения проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Вообще в Linux адрес исходящего трафика определяется интерфейсом, через который он уходит (что в свою очередь определяется правилами маршрутизации).
В вашем случае не видно, какие маски подсетей имеют алиасы, и все ли они принадлежат одной сети или нет.

Если они принадлежат не одной сети,
то вам нужно просто посмотреть правила маршрутизации и сделать так, чтобы трафик уходил через соответствующую сеть. Если

Принудительно маршрутизировать определённый трафчик через определённый интерфейс (в данном случае алиас) вы можете так:

```
route add -host 192.168.2.105 dev eth0:1
```

Кроме того, вы можете поменять IP-адрес уходящих пакетов с помощью `iptables`, в данном случае действия `SNAT`. Этот метод очень гибок, поскольку позволяет выбирать адреса отправителя на основе самых разнообразных правил (не только кому он адресуется, но и на какой порт, от какого процесса, от какого пользователя и так далее).

[image: Путь IP пакета в iptables/netfilter]

*Путь IP пакета в iptables/netfilter; источник: http://www.billauer.co.il/ipmasq-html.html*

POSTROUTING это цепочка, которая применяется практически у самого выхода из стека, уже после того как маршрутизация пройдена и известно куда отправляется пакет. Здесь-то вам и нужно применить трансляцию адресов отправителя, действие SNAT (source NAT).

Просто устанавливайте желаемый адрес с помощью `iptables` на исходящие пакеты (естественно, я предполагаю тут, что у вас все адреса доступны для маршрутизации снаружи, и вопрос только в том как заставить трафик уходить с определённого адреса; ответы будут приходить, очевидно, тоже на этот адрес, поэтому маршрутизация должна работать).

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 100.100.102.201 -j SNAT --to-source 100.100.101.201
```

Здесь я заставляю пакеты, уходящие с `100.100.102.201` уходить с `100.100.101.201`.

Об этом и других интересных методах, используемых для настройки маршрутизации и управления трафиком Linux можно подробнее почитать в бессмертном труде *Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO* (lartc) на сайте lartc.org:

- http://www.lartc.org/ (англ.)
- http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/LARTC/ (рус.)

Answer (score 0):

В целом для системы указать предпочитаемый IP скорее всего не получится. Но обычно любое сетевое приложение позволяет указать IP, с которого оно будет работать. Courier не должен быть исключением, поскольку для почтовиков этот вопрос особенно актуален. Поищите в настройках, сейчас у Вас там явно стоит значение по умолчанию 0.0.0.0.

Прошу прощения, невнимательно прочитал вопрос. Почтовый **клиент** курьер? А при чем тут тогда PTR и доставка почты? И честно говоря Courier Mail Server вроде как всю жизнь виндовым был. Если Вам требуется более точный ответ, то уточните пожалуйста какую именно почтовую программу и в каком режиме Вы используете.